# How to handle both width and height without conflict?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I woud like that if my viewport width is smaller than 330px, the paragraphs font will be 9px, whatever its height.

In the same time, I also would like that if my viewport height is smaller than 330px, the paragraphs font will be 9px, whatever its width.

I have tried different orders, with or without `!important` keywords, I can't achieve the expected result. 
There is always either the width or the height rule which conflicts with the other.

Could I handle such situation in CSS?

[Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/cm6ehd4p/1/) :

```
p{
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media (max-width:600px){
    p{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:440px){
    p{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:330px){
    p{
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}


@media (max-height:600px){
    p{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media (max-height:440px){
    p{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-height:330px){
    P{
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use logic for `@media` queries. You can read more about them [here](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).

For your problem solution would be code below (as comma creates a OR condition)

```
@media (max-width: 330px), (max-height: 330px) {
  p { font-size: 9px; }
}
```

Comment: Just see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpc3n2b5/). It works as it should (at least if I understood you correctly). The thing is, that the order of `@media` queries is important